# System.ArgumentException in Visual Studio 2015 Designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

The designer works like normal right? Well then suddenly , I get a error message.

```
System.ArgumentException
An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Telemetry.VsTelemetryService.RegisterDesignerProcessSession(Int32 pid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Feedback.WatsonTracker.RegisterSession(Int32 processID)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.DesignerSessionTracker.RecordDesignerStart(Int32 processID, String isolationTargetIdentifier, Boolean mockCustomTypes, String buildConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

So, I was like: Ok. Just a simple message, nothing much. So I try to look for a solution. NOTHING. I have been searching for four days straight, trying to get this to work. But It just doesn't. I tried repairing, uninstalling then reinstalling, I even tried the devenv /resetuserdata and devenv.exe /safemode, Still doesn't work. EVEN TRYING TO CREATE A NEW USER, THEN TRY IT. Nothing. I went far to install the 15' update, STILL NOTHING. The error won't go away. I even try it in Blend! Still doesn't work. I even installed the Windows 10 Anniversary Update! Still won't work.

Can someone help.

Comment: install the latest update for VS2015 upd3, it includes XAML designer fixes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt752379.aspx

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: run Vs in safe mode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get: Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error.

Comment: submit it to Microsoft via IDE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632287.aspx) or connect: connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/

Comment: Submitted it thru IDE.

Comment: ok, now hope they fix it in a new update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by deleting a file called "program" in the drive the program is running on.